# Is this the correct syntax for SQLite for making nulls appear last?

Tags: sqlite, null

```
select * from table1
order by case Language when null then 1 else 0 end, Language
```

No matter which way I play around with it, it always displays null values first. Is there a standard way to allow non null values to take ordering precedence?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need `WHEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY Language IS NULL, Language
```

Operator `IS` will return 1 on true, 0 otherwise ([Operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)).

EDIT: Dealing with empty `TEXT`, also:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY Language IS NULL OR Language='', Language
```

`ORDER BY` clause uses two fields:

1. `Language IS NULL OR Language=''`. That's a boolean expression (resulting in `0` (false) or `1` (true) in SQLite), same as `(Language IS NULL) OR (Language='')`
2. When first field has same results, second fiels is used: `Language`.

This way, whenever `Language` is `NULL` or empty `TEXT`, first field will be `1`, relying those results after other results, evaluated to `0`. Then, second field is used to sort all results which `Language` has content.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's what I thought, but it's still spitting out nulls first into my datagrid. My table has one row with French as the Language, 5 rows English, and a few hundred null. Top to bottom, the nulls are displayed first, then English, then French, whereas it should be English, french, then nulls. My query is SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Language IS NULL, Language - is this the correct result for the query?

Comment: Good point - I tried: SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY CASE WHEN Language IS NULL OR language ="" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  

It displays the nulls, English, French - exactly the reverse of what you would think.

Comment: Are sure you're dealing with `NULL`? Aren't those values zero length `TEXT`?

Comment: Your query should be: `SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY Language IS NULL OR language='', Language;`

Comment: Thsnkd LS_dev - that works. Would you mind walking me through what it's doing? I can't see the connection between what it says and the result.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the `is` operator when checking for `null`

```
select * from table1
order by case when Language is null then 1 else 0 end, 
         Language
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of LS_dev's answer to UNIONs. Not a nice way, but I can't figure out any other way to make it work, since the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> if the SELECT is a compound SELECT, then ORDER BY expressions that are not aliases to output columns must be exactly the same as an expression used as an output column.

```
select * from (
    SELECT * FROM table1 -- but this select can have union in it
) ORDER BY Language IS NULL or Language = '', Language
```